# PHP -> Json, access to nested Arrays

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get access to a nested information coming from json using PHP. What I have got so far:
the following Json

```html
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2021-02-05T16:59:45.379+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "MatchLevel": "city",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "City": 1
            },
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_ZJPKK1T.yfVXpHzv5zfPOC",
              "LocationType": "point",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 48.13642,
                "Longitude": 11.57755
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 48.13642,
                  "Longitude": 11.57755
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 48.24824,
                  "Longitude": 11.36084
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 48.06175,
                  "Longitude": 11.72291
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "München, Bayern, Deutschland",
                "Country": "DEU",
                "State": "Bayern",
                "County": "München (Stadt)",
                "City": "München",
                "PostalCode": "80331",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Deutschland",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Bayern",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "München (Stadt)",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Trying to access the 'NavigationPosition' -> Latitude and Longitude.
So I use json_decode to access the external API. I try to loop with foreach to access the nested array elements but no success so far so I decided to ask you for help. I only get info about MetaInfo that it is an array, but thats all... Thank you I don't get it and need a hint.

```html
foreach($json_data as $elem)  {
  echo($elem['MetaInfo']);
   echo("<br/>");
}
```

When printing out  print_r($elem['View'] I get the following PHP:

```html
[0] => Array (
    [_type] => SearchResultsViewType
    [ViewId] => 0
    [Result] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [Relevance] => 1
            [MatchLevel] => city
            [MatchQuality] => Array (
                [City] => 1
                )
            [Location] => Array (
                [LocationId] => NT_okXlwMMLN7VL.8UaGPioOC
                [LocationType] => point
                [DisplayPosition] => Array (
                    [Latitude] => 48.17105
                    [Longitude] => 11.81632
                    )
                [NavigationPosition] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                        [Latitude] => 48.17105
                        [Longitude] => 11.81632
                        )
                    )
                [MapView] => Array (
                    [TopLeft] => Array (
                        [Latitude] => 48.18599
                        [Longitude] => 11.76932
                        )
                    [BottomRight] => Array (
                        [Latitude] => 48.1497
                        [Longitude] => 11.83995
                        )
                    )
                [Address] => Array (
                    [Label] => Poing, Bayern, Deutschland
                    [Country] => DEU
                    [State] => Bayern
                    [County] => Ebersberg
                    [City] => Poing
                    [PostalCode] => 85586
                    [AdditionalData] => Array (
                        [0] => Array (
                            [value] => Deutschland
                            [key] => CountryName
                            )
                        [1] => Array (
                            [value] => Bayern
                            [key] => StateName
                            )
                        [2] => Array (
                            [value] => Ebersberg
                            [key] => CountyName
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Thank you.
Adam

Comment: Are you passing in true for a 2nd argument of json decode (for associative array)? What happens if you print_r($elem['View']); ?

Comment: True -> yes, Full code is:
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($json_data as $elem)  {
 print_r($elem['View']); 
   echo("<br/>");
}

Comment: $elem['View'][0]['Result'][0]['Location']['NavigationPosition'][0]['Latitude'] ?

Comment: @RyanH YES! Thank you. How do you look at the php array - I don't get it to be honest. It there a tool which 'translates' it or something? THANKS!

Comment: @Adamski json arrays when decoded get numeric indexes ... you can see it in your output `[0] => Array ` <-- since there is nothing to associate to for from the source object it just gets a numeric index value.

Answer (score 0):

There is one-stop solution for accessing data from nested structures:

```
<?php

function getFromNested($source, array $path)
{
    $result = null;
    getFromNestedRecursive($source, array_reverse($path), $result);
    return $result;
}

function isArrayAssoc(array $input): bool
{
    if([] === $input) {
        return false;
    }
    return array_keys($input) !== range(0, count($input) - 1);
}


function getFromNestedRecursive($source, array $pathStack, &$result): void
{
    // let's iterate every path part from stack
    while(count($pathStack)) {
        if(is_array($source) && !isArrayAssoc($source)) {
            // the result will be multiple
            if(!is_array($result)) {
                $result = [];
            }
            // and we need to use recursive call for each item of this array
            foreach($source as $item) {
                getFromNestedRecursive($item, $pathStack, $result);
            }
            // we don't need to do something in this recursive branch
            return;
        }

        $key = array_pop($pathStack);

        if(is_array($source)) {
            if(!array_key_exists($key, $source)) {
                // path part key is missing in source array
                // we cannot go deeper
                return;
            }
            // go to the next nested level
            $source = $source[$key];
        } elseif(is_object($source)) {
            $getterName = 'get'.ucfirst($key);
            if(method_exists($source, $getterName)) {
                // go to the next nested level
                $source = $source->{$getterName}();
            } elseif(property_exists($source, $key)) {
                // go to the next nested level
                $source = $source->{$key};
            } else {
                // path part key is missing in source object
                // we cannot go deeper
                return;
            }
        } else {
            // source is scalar, so we can't go to the next depth level
            // we cannot go deeper
            return;
        }

        // when it's not the last iteration of the stack
        // and the source is non-associative array (list)
        if(count($pathStack) && is_array($source) && !isArrayAssoc($source)) {
            // the result will be multiple
            if(!is_array($result)) {
                $result = [];
            }
            // and we need to use recursive call for each item of this array
            foreach($source as $item) {
                getFromNestedRecursive($item, $pathStack, $result);
            }
            // we don't need to do something in this recursive branch
            return;
        }
    }

    // now path stack is empty — we reached target value of given path in source argument
    // so if result is multiple
    if(is_array($result)) {
        // we append source to result
        $result[] = $source;
    } else {
        // result is single
        $result = $source;
    }
    // that's all folks!
}

$data = json_decode('{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2021-02-05T16:59:45.379+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "MatchLevel": "city",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "City": 1
            },
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_ZJPKK1T.yfVXpHzv5zfPOC",
              "LocationType": "point",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 48.13642,
                "Longitude": 11.57755
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 48.13642,
                  "Longitude": 11.57755
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 48.24824,
                  "Longitude": 11.36084
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 48.06175,
                  "Longitude": 11.72291
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "München, Bayern, Deutschland",
                "Country": "DEU",
                "State": "Bayern",
                "County": "München (Stadt)",
                "City": "München",
                "PostalCode": "80331",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Deutschland",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Bayern",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "München (Stadt)",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}', true);

$timestamp = getFromNested($data, ['Response', 'MetaInfo', 'Timestamp']);
var_dump($timestamp); // 2021-02-05T16:59:45.379+0000

$addressesLabels = getFromNested($data, ['Response', 'View', 'Result', 'Location', 'Address', 'Label']);
var_dump($addressesLabels); // ["München, Bayern, Deutschland"]
```

Also you can use it from my package: https://github.com/Smoren/nested-accessor-php